# Basic DataGridView questions

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridvew with a bindinglist whose datasource is to an intersection table.  I have an another bindinglist which acts as a lookup and is bound to one of the columns that is a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn type.  I have simplified the binding lists as shown below:

```
public IList<Flight> flights = new List<Flight>()
{
    new Flight { DepartureID = 1, DestinationID = 1, FlightNumber = "101" },
    new Flight { DepartureID = 2, DestinationID = 2, FlightNumber = "202" },
    new Flight { DepartureID = 3}
};

public IList<Departure> departures = new List<Departure>()
{   
    new Departure {ID = 1, City = "Toronto"},
    new Departure {ID = 2, City = "Chicago"},
    new Departure {ID = 3, City = "New York"}
};

public IList<Destination> destinations = new List<Destination>()
{
    new Destination {ID = 1, City = "London"},
    new Destination {ID = 2, City = "Paris"},
    new Destination {ID = 3, City = "Amsterdam"}
};
```

I have five columns in my datagridview:

- Depature ID: Textbox
- Departure: Textbox
- Destination ID: Textbox
- Destination: Combobox
- Flight Number: Textbox

I have three questions:

1)  The departures are readonly.  I would like to display the ID and the city.  How can I add textbox to automatically look up the City value.  I thought of the OnCellPainting event and looking it up but the e.Value is readonly.  Is there some OnCellDrawing event similar to Delphi.

2) On the combobox for Destinations, once an user selects a value from the combobox, how do I also update the Destination ID also?

3) How do I handle the scenario where I only have values for Departure (e.g. this record (`new Flight { DepartureID = 3}`) throws an invalid value error because there's no value for the combobox to lookup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The easiest way to set your Departure city would be using a `ComboBox` like the destination. Binding it to the list of Destinations and marking this column as `ReadOnly`. This would handle the Departure with no code. 
2) You should bind your `DataGridView` and your `List` of flights with a `BindingSource`. Because your `ComboBox` `ValueMember` is your ID and your `DisplayMember` is the name of the city, it will automatically update your ID.
3) If you want to bind your data, the template should be the same. You should  always have a destination and flight number in your list. If they don't have value, set them to `null`. You're gonna be able to handle the `null` value while you can't handle a non-existent attribute.
`new Flight { DepartureID = 3, DestinationID = null, FlightNumber = null }`

Comment: Thanks for the responses Gabriel.  I was hoping not to use a readonly combobox but just a straight textbox.  Is there an OnDrawEvent similar to the Delphi DBGrid where I can do my lookup there?

Comment: You can always change the lookup of your controls with the OnDrawEvent, but i'm not familiar with redrawing controls. I'm sure there are plenty of tutorial if you google it.

Comment: Thanks Again but I don't see any OnDrawEvent of the DataGridView.  Ideally I would like the OnDrawCellEvent not just the whole grid or on the columns themselves.  Also I should thank you for suggesting that I make Flight.DestinationID nullable as that works nicely.

Comment: Found http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/winformsdatacontrols/thread/cc851529-3699-4928-8497-be391dfa6df4 and it explains that if I set the combobox displayStyle to nothing, a textbox like value is shown.  Yippee - my problems are solved.